# JSON Schema: Input malformed

Tags: python, json, jsonschema

I'm using Tornado_JSON which is based on jsonschema and there is a problem with my schema definition. I tried fixing it in an online schema validator and the problem seems to lie in `"additionalItems": True`. `True` with capital `T` works for python and leads to an error in the online validator (`Schema is invalid JSON.`). With `true` the online validator is happy and the example json validates against the schema, but my python script doesn't start anymore (`NameError: name 'true' is not defined`). Can this be resolved somehow?

```
@schema.validate(
        """input_schema={
            'type': 'object',
            'properties': {
                        'DB': {
                            'type': 'number'
                        },
                        'values': {
                            'type': 'array',
                            'items': [
                                {
                                    'type': 'array',
                                    'items': [
                                        {
                                            'type': 'string'
                                        },
                                        {
                                            'type': [
                                                'number',
                                                'string',
                                                'boolean',
                                                'null'
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            'additionalItems': true
                        }
            }
        },
        input_example={
            'DB': 22,
            'values': [['INT', 44],['REAL', 33.33],['CHAR', 'b']]
        }"""
)
```

*I changed it according to your comments (* ***external file with json.loads()*** *). Perfect. Thank you.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the schema in a triple-quoted string or an external file, then parse it with `json.loads()`.  Use the lower-case spelling.

Answer (score 0):

The error stems from trying to put a builtin Python datatype into a JSON schema.  The latter is a template syntax that is used to check type consistency and should not hold actual data.  Instead, under `input_schema` you'll want to define `"additionalItems"` to be of `{ "type": "boolean" }` and then add it to the test JSON in your `input_example` with a boolean after for testing purposes.

Also, I'm not too familiar with Tornado_JSON but it looks like you aren't complying with the schema definition language by placing `"additionalItems"` inside of the `"values"` property.  Bring that up one level.

More specifically, I think what you're trying to do should look like:

```
"values": {
    ...value schema definition...
}
"additionalItems": {
    "type": "boolean"
}
```

And the input examples would become:

```
input_example={
    "DB": 22,
    "values": [['INT', 44],['REAL', 33.33],['CHAR', 'b']],
    "additionalItems": true
}
```

Comment: Thanks bjornsen. It was meant as a schema attribute for allowing more than one item as explained [here](https://github.com/json-schema/json-schema/wiki/additionalItems-and-items).

Comment: Ah, in that case, the issue is that Python is trying to create a dictionary out of the {...} after `input_schema`.  It should work if you triple quote the whole schema definition with a lowercase `true`.